# How to integrate Zoom SDK into flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, zoom-sdk

I am asked to implement zoom into our flutter application.
Upon researching I could see that either I can use a flutter package like flutter_zoom_sdk or directly integrate zoom meeting SDK onto the application.

There is a issue I am facing with integrating the zoom application which is when I use the package (flutter_zoom_sdk) I get the following error :

[Error in debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7D4C.png)

What am I supposed to do in order to upgrade the zoom SDK version.

Additionally ,if I have to integrate the Zoom meeting SDK myself for android and IOS separately what would the steps be for the same ?

Functionally the task is very simple. Upon clicking a button user must join a zoom meeting and attend it from within the app itself. After user is done with the meeting continue with the normal flow.

User is however not able to join meeting as the error I get is that Zoom SDK version is too low for the flutter package I am using.

Comment: you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your application on https://marketplace.zoom.us . After that, you need to download the SDK package for android of the version you need and take from there two libs of the Zoom Meeting SDK - commonlib.aar and mobilertc.aar.

These libs should be put in the android/libs folder in flutter_zoom_sdk, and then run "flutter pub run flutter_zoom_sdk:unzip_zoom_sdk".

However, I'm not sure if flutter_zoom_sdk will work with the latest versions of the Zoom Meeting SDK for Android. For example, I don't see in their @Override for newly added method in ZoomSDKAuthenticationListener, etc.(https://github.com/evilrat/flutter_zoom_sdk/blob/458afbf65883e8b5f87b8650c158861795305e88/android/src/main/java/com/evilratt/flutter_zoom_sdk/FlutterZoomSdkPlugin.java#L190)